# Prettier disable on certain languages not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

On VS Code, I installed the prettier extensions, and since it doesn't support EJS, I added`"prettier.disableLanguages": [ "ejs", ".ejs" ]` to the setting.json file. This also shows up in the regular settings under `Prettier: Disable Languages`. Despite this, prettier *keeps on* re-formatting my EJS, which is super frustrating. How do I stop prettier from modifying a certain language besides this method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Prettier knows nothing about EJS, it doesn't understand what you wrote in `prettier.disableLanguages`. Also VS Code considers `.ejs` files HTML. This not exactly accurate conclusion is passed to the Prettier extension, which in turn passes it to Prettier, so Prettier tries to format your files as pure HTML.

Try adding `*.ejs` to the `.prettierignore` file. You can read more about it here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 5):

Your can add this
`"[html]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false },`
in your settings.json file in VSCode it will prevent auto formating html files, prettier still not have any ignore for .ejs files.
As .ejs files are still taken as html files by prettier.

Comment: The timing of this answer is something else cause it's the only that made me realise I needed `formatOnSave` instead of `defaultFormatter` like literally every other guide and answer out there suggests.